# Node automatically move in random direction

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a ball that automatically moves forward in a random direction once it is created. I've tried creating a random angle from 0-360 and having the node rotate and then having an impulse applied to the node, but the node simply stays there once it is created, so I can't tell if it is just the impulse that is not working or if the rotate isn't even working.

```
    enemy.size =  CGSize(width: 20, height:20)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2)
    enemy.color = UIColor(red:255.0,green:0.0,blue:0.0,alpha:1.0)
    enemy.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    self.addChild(enemy)
```

this is just to create the enemy, but i dont know how to apply the random direction and  forward movement.

```
 enemy.size =  CGSize(width: 20, height:20)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2)
    enemy.color = UIColor(red:255.0,green:0.0,blue:0.0,alpha:1.0)
    enemy.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:10)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
     self.addChild(enemy)
    let vec = CGVector(dx: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 50.0, dy: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 50.0)
    enemy.physicsBody!.applyForce(vec)
```

this is my edited code.The enemy ball now moves when it is hit by another ball, but I want the enemy ball to just automatically move on its own. Right now it stays in the place in the middle of the screen until hit.

Comment: Is `enemy.physicsBody` equal to nil? The code you have written will compile and not crash if it is nil, but you won't get what you are expecting.

Comment: that is not possible.  you are applying a force.  Your issue is your vector is 2.0,2.0,  that means you are applying a force of max 4 pixels.  You are not going to see much change with such a weak force.

Comment: Sometimes the ball moves on its own but sometimes it stays still until it is hit by another ball. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Like Gary already pointed out in the comments you wanna be sure that you have created an added a `physicsBody` to your `SKNode`. If you haven't, some neat documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody).

Now for applying a random force. You basically want to generate a random `CGVector` and use [applyForce](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520430-applyforce) on your physics body.

To generate a random vector:

```
let vec = CGVector(dx: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 50.0, dy: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 50.0)
```

`arc4random_uniform` creates a random number between 0 and your upper bound which is passed as a parameter. Then I divide it a bit in order to get a number between 0 and 2. You should tweak that to your needs.

Then just use `enemy.physicsBody!.applyForce(vec)`. Note my use of `!` mark. Be sure that you have created and applied a physics body otherwise this will crash.

Comment: your math does not account for negative, so you are only doing 0 - 90.  I would recommend getting a random angle and using `let vec = CGVector(dx:cos(randomAngle) * magnitude, dy:sin(randomAngle) * magnitude))`

Comment: Thanks for the response! It did make it so the ball can now be moved when hit by another ball, but I'd like for it to automatically move on its own at a random angle. Could you check out my edited code and help me figure out what the problem seems to be?